# Robot who becomes poetry critic and won't do assigned job

Tags: story-identification

Can't recall the author or name of this story, though the idea and literary part would suggest Jack Williamson I can't find mention of it specifically. A self-aware robot, designed to work in the conditions on Venus, refuses to do that work and becomes a contributor to artsy poetry and "lit-crit" journals. the engineers in charge of the robot have to convince the art community that sf adventure is the new "genre" of choice for the world of literature, and by doing so, create the urge in the robot to go and do the job required while writing a book about the experience. It features som e jibes at the Literati community, including a journal called "Pierce, Arrow! The journal of literate insights" IIRC. Anyone please know the actual title - Google is no help - and/or the author?

Comment: There once was a lady from Venus... No, wait, I can't finish *that* poem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are thinking of [**"The Critique of Impure Reason,"**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58275) by **Poul Anderson**. He could be surprisingly funny when he set his mind to it! (He and his buddy Gordon R. Dickson also collaborated on a bunch of "Hoka" stories, and if you haven't read 'em yet, you really ought to!)

The story was first published in *If,* the November 1962 issue. But it's been reprinted on many occasions, according to ISFDB; most often in successive editions of the Poul Anderson anthology titled *Time and Stars*. (I believe I last reread that story, a couple of years ago, in my own paperback copy of that collection.)

Your memory of the plot is pretty accurate. Literature in this future era had gotten to the point where everything was expected to be full of subtle psychological symbolism and the like, and two human characters, as a hoax intended to appeal to the robot's sensibilities by persuading it that great insights could be gained from exploring new worlds, created an imitation of the sort of two-fisted adventure tale, set on an alien planet, which had once been so popular in the pulp magazines of the first half of the 20th Century. Their novel was written very hastily, with lots of shameless plagiarism from ancient stories which no one would remember, and was given the catchy title of *Thunder Beyond Venus.*

Things spiraled out of control after it turned out, much to everyone's surprise, that there was a *huge* untapped market of ordinary people who honestly liked that sort of thing when they were finally exposed to it for *the first time in their lives!*

Comment: Yes, that would be the one! Thanks for that :)